# How do I add a branch from a new remote to an existing Git project?

Tags: git, git-remote

I have an existing local Git repository and would like to add a branch corresponding to a branch on an unrelated remote Git repo (ideally without the full history<sup>+</sup>), from which I may occasionally pull updates. I've been struggling with how to accomplish this and have come up with

```
git checkout -b template
git remote add framework <repo_url>
git pull --rebase=true framework template:template --force
```

and wonder if this is really the best way to go about it.

Is there a more compact or more idiomatic way to add a branch from a new remote to an existing Git project?

---

<sup>+</sup>The issue with attempting to get just a partial history (with `--depth` as an additional option to the `pull` is that it creates a structure that crashes all my Git tools (Tower, GitX, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the remote with

```
git remote add -t template -f framework <repo_url>
```

which will also fetch the ref for just the one branch on the remote; and then checkout the branch into a new local branch using

```
git checkout -b template framework/template
```

Now you can pull this branch from your original remote from the local branch using

```
git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to use **[`git subtree/submodule`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging)**. Subtree/submodule will create inner repository inside your main repository.

You can read more about submodule and subtree **[here](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/)** and **[here](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-subtree-merges/)**